# Index error in simple keras model

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm using the following code to fit a simple keras model:

```
# Prepare data
x1_dat = []
x2_dat = []
y_dat = []
cs = 3
for session in Sessions_group:
    session = session.split(',')
    for i in xrange(0,len(session)-cs+1):
        x1_dat.append(session[i])
        x2_dat.append(session[i+1])
        y_dat.append(session[i+2])

x1_dat = np.stack(x1_dat)
x2_dat = np.stack(x2_dat)
y_dat = np.stack(y_dat)

# Create model
n_fac = 100
def embedding_input(name, n_in, n_out):
    inp = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int64', name=name)
    emb = Embedding(n_in, n_out, input_length=1)(inp)
    return inp, Flatten()(emb)

vocab_size = len(uniqueArtifacts)
x1_in, x1 = embedding_input('x1', vocab_size, n_fac)
x2_in, x2 = embedding_input('x2', vocab_size, n_fac)
n_hidden = 512
dense_in = Dense(n_hidden, activation='relu')
x1_hidden = dense_in(x1)
dense_hidden = Dense(n_hidden, activation='tanh')
x2_dense = dense_in(x2)
hidden_2 = dense_hidden(x1_hidden)
x2_hidden = merge([x2_dense, hidden_2])
dense_out = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')
x3_out = dense_out(x2_hidden)

# Fit model
model = Model([x1_in, x2_in], x3_out)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
model.fit([x1_dat, x2_dat], y_dat, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=1, verbose = 1)
```

To briefly explain it - I'm trying to predict the third item given  the first 2 items. I pass item1 and item2 through `Dense` layers (`dense_in` in the code), and merge (sum) the output and pass it through another `Dense` layer (`dense_out` in the code) to produce the output.

This seemingly simple code gives me the following error when I execute the `fit` command:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-1912702bd26c> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit([x1_dat, x2_dat], y_dat, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=1, verbose = 1)

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch)
   1194                               val_f=val_f, val_ins=val_ins, shuffle=shuffle,
   1195                               callback_metrics=callback_metrics,
-> 1196                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1197 
   1198     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None):

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch)
    889                 batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
    890                 callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
--> 891                 outs = f(ins_batch)
    892                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
    893                     outs = [outs]

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
    957     def __call__(self, inputs):
    958         assert isinstance(inputs, (list, tuple))
--> 959         return self.function(*inputs)
    960 
    961 

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    896                     node=self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    897                     thunk=thunk,
--> 898                     storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    899             else:
    900                 # old-style linkers raise their own exceptions

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.pyc in raise_with_op(node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    323         # extra long error message in that case.
    324         pass
--> 325     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    326 
    327 

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    882         try:
    883             outputs =\
--> 884                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    885                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)
    886         except Exception:

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.pyc in rval(p, i, o, n)
    870             # default arguments are stored in the closure of `rval`
    871             def rval(p=p, i=node_input_storage, o=node_output_storage, n=node):
--> 872                 r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
    873                 for o in node.outputs:
    874                     compute_map[o][0] = True

/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/subtensor.pyc in perform(self, node, inputs, out_)
   2240 
   2241         if self.set_instead_of_inc:
-> 2242             out[0][inputs[2:]] = inputs[1]
   2243         elif config.cxx:
   2244             inplace_increment(out[0], tuple(inputs[2:]), inputs[1])

IndexError: index 1864798 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2392
Apply node that caused the error: AdvancedIncSubtensor{inplace=False,  set_instead_of_inc=True}(Alloc.0, TensorConstant{1}, ARange{dtype='int64'}.0, Elemwise{Cast{int32}}.0)
Toposort index: 69
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(int8, scalar), TensorType(int64, vector), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(10, 2392), (), (10,), (10,)]
Inputs strides: [(9568, 4), (), (8,), (4,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', array(1, dtype=int8), 'not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[GpuFromHost(AdvancedIncSubtensor{inplace=False,  set_instead_of_inc=True}.0)]]

Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
  File "/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-29-6ef574590fa0>", line 1, in <module>
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
  File "/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 667, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 318, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/objectives.py", line 41, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
    return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)
  File "/home/prateek/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1249, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
    target = T.extra_ops.to_one_hot(target, nb_class=output.shape[-1])

HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

**Further information:**

The total number of values that I'm trying to predict from is 2392.

The index in the error `IndexError: index 1864798 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2392` (1864798 in this case) keeps changing as I re-execute the code.

The output to the following code (the size of my data):

```
x1_dat.shape, x2_dat.shape, y_dat.shape
```

is:

```
((6510,), (6510,), (6510,))
```

How do I go about resolving this error? Any help would be much appreciated.